# как прописать взятие параметров для исполняемого файла из терминала

Tags: bash, macos, chat

Я хочу написать файл, который можно запустить с терминала, в одну строку. Например, как стандартная команда

```
cp from [parameter1] to [parameter2]
```

Я пытаюсь написать такую ​​команду, которая будет записывать много файлов в один. При условии, что список файлов может содержать сам файл для записи. Мне нужно получить что-то вроде

```
sh comm.sh test * .txt test4.txt
```

Которая будет записывать все "тестовые" файлы в test4 один за другим.

---

перенесено из «ответа»:

дело в том, что у меня есть несколько подобных задач, для которых требуется понять этот механизм.

изначально на подобный ответ мне сказали, что это не будет корректно работать. на переписанную надстройку был получен такой же комментарий.

вот она

```
cat  file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt \
        >>  file4.txt &&\
mv  file4.txt file1.txt
```

нет понимания, что конкретно в этом случае будет работать некорректно.

Comment: параметры передаются в [массиве `$@`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0040)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо написания своего велосипеда можно использовать

```
cat ./*.txt > ./output.txt
```

Comment: ссылка на текущий каталог (`./`) выглядит как-то даже излишне. это такое правило оформления принято в macosx?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Почему она выглядит излишне? Если речь идет о файле в текущей папке, то наличие ./ говорит об этом явно и позволяет избежать проблем в контекстах, когда без него путь не будет восприниматься как путь к файлу в текущей папке. Понятия не имею, что принято в macosx

Comment: `в контекстах, когда без него путь не будет восприниматься как путь к файлу в текущей папке` — не смог придумать контекста, в котором пути в команде `cat *.txt > output.txt` могли бы восприниматься как-то иначе. у вас есть пример?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я тоже долго думал на счет примера. А вот он: `touch ./'-a file.txt'`. Затем попробуйте выполнить оба варианта.

Comment: ах, вот что вы подразумевали под «контекстом». ну, такой «контекст» имеет [универсальное решение прямо в стандарте posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04): `it could safely do it as: foo -- -myfile`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Я не писал, что в этой команде есть такой контекст, и даже не разбирался, есть ли он там или нет. Я писал, что явное указание префикса обеспечит правильную интерпретацию пути независимо от контекста. Потому что не хочется каждый раз тратить время на выяснение этого контекста, и, тем более, не хочется тратить прорву времени в случае, когда контекст был определен не правильно и код стал работать не так, как планировалось.

Answer (score -1):

дело в том, что у меня есть несколько подобных задач, для которых требуется понять этот механизм...
изначально на подобный ответ мне сказали, что это не будет корректно работать. на переписанную надстройку был получен такой же комментарий...вот она

cat  file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt 
>>  file4.txt &&
mv  file4.txt file1.txt

нет понимания, что конкретно в этом случае будет работать некорректно.

Comment: это стоило не публиковать как ответ (ведь ответом это не является), а написать прямо в тексте вопроса (нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса).

Comment: перенёс в текст вопроса.